# Elasticsearch Connection 8.4

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-8

I am trying to connect my elasticsearch through thi way:
defined('ES_SERVER_HOST')
|| define('ES_SERVER_HOST', 'localhost');

defined('ES_SERVER_PORT')
|| define('ES_SERVER_PORT', 9200);

defined('ES_SERVER_INDEX')
|| define('ES_SERVER_INDEX', 'activities');

defined('ES_SERVER_URL')
|| define('ES_SERVER_URL', ES_SERVER_HOST.":".ES_SERVER_PORT."/".ES_SERVER_INDEX);

but getting error:

Unknown error
RESETCONEECTION

Could anyone help me with where I am making mistake.

Comment: can you clarify what language and client library you are using please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.